# Why are get requests sent to my application when I copy and paste the link?

Tags: flask, heroku, outlook

I deploy a Flask app on Heroku. Then, I copy and paste the link to an email in Microsoft Outlook. When I copy and paste the link, exactly 5 get requests are sent to the app. This happens without me clicking the link, before I send the email.

The hostname sending the request is msnbot-157-55-39-74.search.msn.com with the ISP Microsoft Bingbot.

I don't experience the same issue when I copy and paste the link in Gmail.

Why is this happening and how do I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean a mailbox at outlook.com (which has nothing to do with the desktop Outlook, which [outlook] tag is for).

The link is probed to make sure it does not point to anything dangerous or suspect. It will also be checked when the message is received.

If your server does something automatically when the link is hit, you are out of luck. You need to point it to a page where the user must explicitly click on a link or a button instead.